# Can SVG path rendering be anti-aliased beyond geometricPrecision option?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I'm aware of the geometricPrecision style option for SVG however paths still exhibit an ugly amount of aliasing. The data set I'm using is fairly dense at around 400 points. Have a look at the red path below.

[image: path aliasing present even when geometricPrecision style active]

Are there any other options for anti-aliasing paths in SVG?

**EDIT:**

The line is created from tab-separated data as follows (minus the unimportant details):

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

x.domain([0,240000]);
y.domain([0,30]);


var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.income); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.tax); });
...
...
...

g.append("path").classed("linedata", true)
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#e04444")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2.3)
        .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: If you showed us *how* the red path is created, with actual code, we could think about interpolating that path, instead of dealing with SVG precision.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I added some details.

Comment: Filter the path data to exclude points that are within 1.5px of the previous included point and draw again. You may be experiencing aliasing from too much data, not from poor rendering.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @wrkyle Phrogz is correct: when I wrote *"with actual code"* in my comment I was thinking *"with actual data"*, sorry for that mistake. The problem is that you have too much data points, and that's why I suggested interpolating: you can reduce the data points and use a D3 curve. This answer of mine at Code Review can be useful to you: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/171946/143592

Comment: That did the trick. If one of you wants to post a brief answer I can confirm it. Otherwise I'll answer it myself tomorrow.

Comment: @wrkyle you can answer it yourself, and accept your own answer after a couple of days. But please write an answer useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the problem here is not one of aliasing or interpolation of dense data. While I did eventually optimize the density of data to the path curvature the problem wound up being the `d3.scale` I was using to map data values to SVG pixel values.

If you create a D3 scale with `rangeRound` instead of `range` it maps to the nearest pixel forcing the rendered path to appear aliased. Simply switching `rangeRound` to `range` results in a much smoother path regardless of the method used to interpolate the data.

[image]